# how to check repeat row of for loop in django

Tags: python, django

I am new in django and I created 3 tables for data

```
class student_admission(models.Model):
    Student = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    Father = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    Date = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length= 250)
    City = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    College = models.CharField(max_length= 250)
    Branch = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    Semester = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    Occupation = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    Pin = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    Phone = models.IntegerField(default=20)
    FatherPhone = models.IntegerField(default=20)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length= 100)

class course_content(models.Model):
    course = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    Code = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class student_course(models.Model):
    Student_id= models.ForeignKey(student_admission,on_delete=None)
    Course_id = models.ForeignKey(course_content,on_delete=None)
```

in the `student_admission` table I save the student informations 
and in the `course_content` table course list is saved if student submit this form then he select course in my course_content list they are also select multiple course this course I save in `student_course` table

and I show this data on my website using this `view function`

```
def table(request):
    data = student_course.objects.all().prefetch_related("Student_id","Course_id")
    d = {"data":data}  
    return render(request,"html/tables.html",d)
```

and I print data on html page

```
 <tbody>

                            {% for item in data %}
                        <tr>
                          <td>{{item.Student_id.id}}</td>
                          <td>{{item.Student_id.Student}}</td>
                          <td>{{item.Student_id.Father}}</td>
                          <td>{{item.Student_id.Date}}</td>
                          <td>{{ item.Course_id.course}}</td>
                          <td>{{item.Student_id.Gender}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </tbody>
```

all is work properly, I got my result like this [image: this is my html page of student table]

But I want:

If student select 3 course then I got only one row of this student and both 3 course in one column like this (python,business, php+)

Please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of querying all objects of `student_course` model, query the list of all students in your view like this:

```
def table(request):
    data = student_admission.objects.all()
    d = {"data": data}  
    return render(request,"html/tables.html", d)
```

Then in your html template:

```
<tbody>
    {% for stud in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{stud.id}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.Student}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.Father}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.Date}}</td>
        <td>
            {% for stud_course in stud.student_course_set.all %}  // this loop will get all the student_course of this student
                <span>{{ stud_course.Course_id.course }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
        <td>{{stud.Gender}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

This will get you expected results. If you still get some error, comment below.

Also on side note you should follow [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming convention your naming your class and variables. It makes them easier to read and understand. In short class names should follow Pascal Camel Case so they they should `LookLikeThis` while variable names should follow Snake Case and should `look_like_this`.

Comment: sir i got my result 100% right but sir can you explain me seccond for loop i am not understand this correctly

Comment: In your model `student_course` you have a foreign key to model `student_admission`. Therefore just like from an object of model `student_course` you can get its related `student_admission` object(like this: `obj.Student_id`). From `student_admission` object you can also get all `student_course` object related to it, it's called reverse relationship(I think). By default you use `modelname_set`(all lower case), but you can change it too, while defining the foreign key. So in this case `obj.student_course_set.all()`, since you are using it in template functions dont require `()`.

Comment: here you go https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward
Changing related_name: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name